# Namespace is not declared

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, namespaces, public

I want to use the `dbConnectDBOStr` connection string any where within my project so that if the datbase connections change I only have to change it in one file

This is currently bringing up an error, any one know what im doing wrong??

Please help I am really stuck on this thank you!!

**default.aspx**

```
Imports Pirelli.dbPirelli
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strCmd As String
    Dim dbCmd As SqlCommand
    Dim oConn As SqlConnection
    Dim dbReader As SqlDataReader
    oConn = New SqlConnection(dbConnectDBOStr)
```

dbPirelli.vb

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Namespace Pirelli
Public Class dbPirelli
   'Database Server - ENABLE ONE ONLY
    Public Const strServerName As String = "[Server]"  'DEV
    Public Const dbConnectDBOStr As String = "uid=[USER];password=[PASS];database=[DB];server=" & strServerName & ";Connection Timeout=60;"
End Class
End Namespace
```

This error

**Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** `BC30451: Name 'dbConnectDBOStr' is not declared.`

**Source Error:**

```
Line 21: 
Line 22: 
Line 23: oConn = New SqlConnection(dbConnectDBOStr)
Line 24: 
Line 25: oConn.Open()
```